# How to change TextField text from Store with flutter_flux?

Tags: flutter

In the [flutter_flux example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_flux) when we commit a new message, the `_currentMessage` is emptied but the `TextField` does not reflect that changes.

This is the code in the store:

```dart
triggerOnAction(commitCurrentMessageAction, (ChatUser me) {
      final ChatMessage message =
          new ChatMessage(sender: me, text: _currentMessage);
      _messages.add(message);
      _currentMessage = '';
    });
```

The view uses a `TextEditingController` as a controller for the `TextField` Widget so I understand why it is not updated.

How can we empty the `TextField` from the Store with flutter_flux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** The `flutter_flux` example has been updated since I posted this answer, and it now correctly discards message in the `TextField` but in a better way. You should check it out.

---

I think the correct way would be to move the `TextEditingController` to the `ChatMessageStore`, instead of simply keeping the `currentMessage` in that store. Then you would be able to empty the text field by calling `clear()` on the `TextEditingController`.

Generally speaking, the state values which would normally be kept in `FooState` in vanilla flutter would go into a `Store` when using `flutter_flux`. Since you would normally create and keep a `TextEditingController` in a `State`, I think it's more natural to keep it in a `Store` anyways.

The updated `ChatMessageStore` would look something like this:

```dart
class ChatMessageStore extends Store {
  ChatMessageStore() {
    triggerOnAction(commitCurrentMessageAction, (ChatUser me) {
      final ChatMessage message =
          new ChatMessage(sender: me, text: currentMessage);
      _messages.add(message);
      _msgController.clear();
    });
  }

  final List<ChatMessage> _messages = <ChatMessage>[];
  final TextEditingController _msgController = new TextEditingController();

  List<ChatMessage> get messages =>
      new List<ChatMessage>.unmodifiable(_messages);
  TextEditingController get msgController => _msgController;
  String get currentMessage => _msgController.text;

  bool get isComposing => currentMessage.isNotEmpty;
}
```

Note that we no longer need the `setCurrentMessageAction`, as the `TextEditingController` would take care of the text value change itself.

Then, the `msgController` defined in `ChatScreen` widget could be removed and the `_buildTextComposer` could be updated accordingly.

```dart
Widget _buildTextComposer(BuildContext context, ChatMessageStore messageStore,
    ChatUserStore userStore) {
  final ValueChanged<String> commitMessage = (String _) {
    commitCurrentMessageAction(userStore.me);
  };

  ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
  return new Row(children: <Widget>[
    new Flexible(
        child: new TextField(
            key: const Key("msgField"),
            controller: messageStore.msgController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter message'),
            onSubmitted: commitMessage)),
    new Container(
        margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
        child: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.send),
            onPressed:
                messageStore.isComposing ? () => commitMessage(null) : null,
            color: messageStore.isComposing
                ? themeData.accentColor
                : themeData.disabledColor))
  ]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Saving view implementation in the model is frowned on in Flux, but the current sample code does a poor job of allowing for an alternative. I'm updating the sample code to demonstrate how you can store the TextEditingController in the Flutter State<> object. I should be able to post the update tomorrow.

Comment: Not sure why TextEditingController is considered a view implementation. It just holds the text data and the current selection, and notifies the views whenever something changes. Wouldn't it be more like a data model to be stored in a Store?

Comment: The TextEditingController is tied to the view implementation. In a larger app, you would either need hundreds of them to match all of the input fields in all of the widgets, or you would need a pool of them that's arbitrarily reused. Neither of these works. In addition, the lifetime of the view is different than the lifetime of the Store.